# Can I make two attributes of a MySQL table always have the same value?

Tags: mysql, attributes

This is the command I put in:

```
create table inventory(
    idx int primary key,
    name varchar(20),
    location varchar(20),
    quantity int);
```

In this table, I want attributes `name` and `location` to share the same value at all times. Can I do this in a table creation statement? Or do I have to set something after creating it?

Comment: You can use `DEFAULT` values for those two fields

Comment: You mean so that they cannot be changed after they're created?

Comment: @Strawberry nope I want one of those two to be changed too when the other one is changed.

Comment: I would suggest then that you only store one or the other. You might look at triggers - but I can't actually think of the logic :-(

Comment: Hmm ok thank you! in fact the answer below with not null ~ @#$ does not work as i want.. think i have to find some other method

Comment: Yes. This kind of problem is often symptomatic of a flawed design

Comment: You didn't state your use case properly on first hand. As @Strawberry pointed out that you need trigger. FYI, answer's been updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set default values for those two fields in the `create table statement`.

```
CREATE TABLE inventory (
    idx INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    NAME VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'DEFAULT VALUE SET',
    location VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'DEFAULT VALUE SET',
    quantity INT
);
```

If you don't provide any values for those two fields while inserting then the default value will persist.

**EDIT:**

Through `before update on trigger` you can accomplish this.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `inventory_trigger`;


DELIMITER //
    CREATE TRIGGER inventory_trigger BEFORE UPDATE ON inventory FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN 
        IF (NEW.name <> OLD.name ) THEN
            SET NEW.location = NEW.name ;
        END IF;
        IF (NEW.location <> OLD.location ) THEN
            SET NEW.name = NEW.location ;
        END IF;
  END//
```

---

If the `location` field changes then this change will also reflect in the `name` column and vice versa.

Comment: Still seems like a daft idea though

Comment: This is the only solution I can think of doing it alone in `MySQL` end. You can contribute to the answer if you would like. @Strawberry

Comment: I would suggest not 'doing it' at all!!

Comment: ha ha. That's what I was guessing. Btw, I agree with you. There are certain issues adopting triggers while there's other way around (application logic).

Comment: christ this one is pretty complicated. thnx a lot!